# Microservice communication with python in Asynchronous manner

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, rabbitmq

I want to trigger Python script from my Spring boot microservices im Asynchronous manner, SO that my Microservice will be notified once the execution of python script completes.Can any one suggest the best approach for this? appreciated if any one provide some reference to sample code.
Thanks in advance!!!
Thanks,
Sudheer

Answer (score 0):

here is very good Example for something like that:
Source: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511454-an-asynchronous-http-server-with-cgi-support/

```
import SimpleAsyncServer

# =============================================================
# An implementation of the HTTP protocol, supporting persistent
# connections and CGI
# =============================================================
import sys
import os
import traceback
import datetime
import mimetypes
import urlparse
import urllib
import cStringIO

class HTTP(SimpleAsyncServer.ClientHandler):

# parameters to override if necessary
    root = os.getcwd()  # the directory to serve files from
    cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin']  # subdirectories for cgi scripts
    logging = True      # print logging info for each request ?
    blocksize = 2 << 16 # size of blocks to read from files and send

    def request_complete(self):
    """In the HTTP protocol, a request is complete if the "end of headers"
    sequence ('\r\n\r\n') has been received
    If the request is POST, stores the request body in a StringIO before
    returning True"""
    terminator = self.incoming.find('\r\n\r\n')
    if terminator == -1:
        return False
    lines = self.incoming[:terminator].split('\r\n')
    self.requestline = lines[0]
    try:
        self.method,self.url,self.protocol = lines[0].strip().split()
    except:
        self.method = None # indicates bad request
        return True
    # put request headers in a dictionary
    self.headers = {}
    for line in lines[1:]:
        k,v = line.split(':',1)
        self.headers[k.lower().strip()] = v.strip()
    # persistent connection
    close_conn = self.headers.get("connection","")
    if (self.protocol == "HTTP/1.1" 
        and close_conn.lower() == "keep-alive"):
        self.close_when_done = False
    # parse the url
    scheme,netloc,path,params,query,fragment = urlparse.urlparse(self.url)
    self.path,self.rest = path,(params,query,fragment)

    if self.method == 'POST':
        # for POST requests, read the request body
        # its length must be specified in the content-length header
        content_length = int(self.headers.get('content-length',0))
        body = self.incoming[terminator+4:]
        # request is incomplete if not all message body received
        if len(body)<content_length:
            return False
        f_body = cStringIO.StringIO(body)
        f_body.seek(0)
        sys.stdin = f_body # compatibility with CGI

    return True

def make_response(self):
    """Build the response : a list of strings or files"""
    if self.method is None: # bad request
        return self.error_resp(400,'Bad request : %s' %self.requestline)
    resp_headers, resp_body, resp_file = '','',None
    if not self.method in ['GET','POST','HEAD']:
        return self.err_resp(501,'Unsupported method (%s)' %self.method)
    else:
        file_name = self.file_name = self.translate_path()
        if not os.path.exists(file_name):
            return self.err_resp(404,'File not found')
        elif self.managed():
            response = self.mngt_method()
        else:
            ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]
            c_type = mimetypes.types_map.get(ext,'text/plain')
            resp_line = "%s 200 Ok\r\n" %self.protocol
            size = os.stat(file_name).st_size
            resp_headers = "Content-Type: %s\r\n" %c_type
            resp_headers += "Content-Length: %s\r\n" %size
            resp_headers += '\r\n'
            if self.method == "HEAD":
                resp_string = resp_line + resp_headers
            elif size > HTTP.blocksize:
                resp_string = resp_line + resp_headers
                resp_file = open(file_name,'rb')
            else:
                resp_string = resp_line + resp_headers + \
                    open(file_name,'rb').read()
            response = [resp_string]
            if resp_file:
                response.append(resp_file)
    self.log(200)
    return response

def translate_path(self):
    """Translate URL path into a path in the file system"""
    return os.path.join(HTTP.root,*self.path.split('/'))

def managed(self):
    """Test if the request can be processed by a specific method
    If so, set self.mngt_method to the method used
    This implementation tests if the script is in a cgi directory"""
    if self.is_cgi():
        self.mngt_method = self.run_cgi
        return True
    return False

def is_cgi(self):
    """Test if url in a cgi directory"""
    for path in self.cgi_directories:
        if self.path.startswith(path):
            rest = self.path[len(path):]
            if not rest or rest.startswith('/'):
                return True
    return False

def run_cgi(self):
    # set CGI environment variables
    self.make_cgi_env()
    # redirect print statements to a cStringIO
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = cStringIO.StringIO()
    # run the script
    try:
        execfile(self.file_name)
    except:
        sys.stdout = cStringIO.StringIO()
        sys.stdout.write("Content-type:text/plain\r\n\r\n")
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
    response = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    if self.method == "HEAD":
        # for HEAD request, don't send message body even if the script
        # returns one (RFC 3875)
        head_lines = []
        for line in response.split('\n'):
            if not line:
                break
            head_lines.append(line)
        response = '\n'.join(head_lines)
    sys.stdout = save_stdout # restore sys.stdout
    # close connection in case there is no content-length header
    self.close_when_done = True
    resp_line = "%s 200 Ok\r\n" %self.protocol
    return [resp_line + response]

def make_cgi_env(self):
    """Set CGI environment variables"""
    env = {}
    env['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = "AsyncServer"
    env['SERVER_NAME'] = "AsyncServer"
    env['GATEWAY_INTERFACE'] = 'CGI/1.1'
    env['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = HTTP.root
    env['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = "HTTP/1.1"
    env['SERVER_PORT'] = str(self.server.port)

    env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = self.method
    env['REQUEST_URI'] = self.url
    env['PATH_TRANSLATED'] = self.translate_path()
    env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = self.path
    env['PATH_INFO'] = urlparse.urlunparse(("","","",self.rest[0],"",""))
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = self.rest[1]
    if not self.host == self.client_address[0]:
        env['REMOTE_HOST'] = self.host
    env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = self.client_address[0]
    env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = str(self.headers.get('content-length',''))
    for k in ['USER_AGENT','COOKIE','ACCEPT','ACCEPT_CHARSET',
        'ACCEPT_ENCODING','ACCEPT_LANGUAGE','CONNECTION']:
        hdr = k.lower().replace("_","-")
        env['HTTP_%s' %k.upper()] = str(self.headers.get(hdr,''))
    os.environ.update(env)

def err_resp(self,code,msg):
    """Return an error message"""
    resp_line = "%s %s %s\r\n" %(self.protocol,code,msg)
    self.close_when_done = True
    self.log(code)
    return [resp_line]

def log(self,code):
    """Write a trace of the request on stderr"""
    if HTTP.logging:
        date_str = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('[%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S]')
        sys.stderr.write('%s - - %s "%s" %s\n' %(self.host,
            date_str,self.requestline,code))

if __name__=="__main__":
    # launch the server on the specified port
    port = 8081
    print "Asynchronous HTTP server running on port %s" %port
    print "Press Ctrl+C to stop"
    server = SimpleAsyncServer.Server('', port)
    HTTP.logging = False
    try:


 SimpleAsyncServer.loop(server,HTTP)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for s in server.client_handlers:
        server.close_client(s)
    print 'Ctrl+C pressed. Closing'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing asynchronous execution in Python would be to use the celery framework. It's really simple to install and setup (basically just pip install), and the semantic for calling a method asynchronously is super clean.

If you are not too bound to Spring you could even switch to the pymacaron microservice framework (basically a flask app that uses swagger to spawn a REST API). Pymacaron (http://pymacaron.com/) supports asynchronous calls by default, via the pymacaron-async module. See the examples here: http://pymacaron.com/async.html